# Pandas : retrieve mapping of pair of column values to replace value in 3rd one

Tags: pandas, loops, dictionary, replace, mapping

I've been wasting a shit ton of time on this so here I go: my dataset from the terrorism data of University of Maryland, has some variables 3 of which are basically: country_name, region_name, nationality name.

I want to synthesize information so I want to use the correspondence between country and region_name to replace my values in nationality with region_of_individual.

| country | region | nationality (to be renamed) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | Europe | France (to be replaced) |
| Irak | Middle-East | Irak (to be replaced) |

I tried this but of course doesn't work : seems .index is not the way to go here...

```
dico = {}
for value in df["nationality"]:
    index = value.index
    clee = value
    valeur = df.loc[index, "region"]
    if clee not in dico.keys(): 
        dico[clee] = []
    dico[clee].append(valeur)
```

I also looked into and tried `df.loc` and also `df.replace` I also tried a `for` loop...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dico = defaultdict(list)

for index, value in df["nationality"].items():
    clee = value
    valeur = df.loc[index, "region"]
    dico[clee].append(valeur)
```

Comment: I added my "if" condition to your code to exclude duplicate values and it works! now I just have to retrieve the values of the dictionary. Thank you :) !